# JS send some number as string and get other number why?

Tags: javascript, string

Hi i have a confusing problem. When i run follow code:

```
console.log(1020462619767967302);
```

but i get in the console follow message

```
"1020462619767967400"
```

I really don't know why the string changes his content.

Please help me.

Comment: where is the string ?? you put a number inside the console.log and it shows a number not a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number you're logging is larger than the largest integer that can be represented in Javascript (9007199254740992). As a result you get rounding errors resulting from the floating point treatment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a string than put:

```
console.log("1020462619767967302");
```

or:

```
var num = "1020462619767967302"

console.log(num);
```

The number you are using is to big.

Comment: i want to send this number per
$.getJSON("../REST/userexist", {facebookid: String(test) },
but i have the same rounded error